# how do I create 23 fps proxies for footage shot in 30 fps and interpreted as 23 fps

Tags: premiere, framerate, intermediate

I am trying to create 23 fps proxies for footage shot in 30 fps and interpreted as 23 fps

I watched and carefully followed the Youtube video that explains exactly this and I am still getting out of sync proxies.

Steps I tried:

- Create my encoding configuration in Adobe Media Encoder with these settings:
  Format: QuickTime, codec: Apple ProRes Proxy, Resolution: 480 x 270, Frames/s: 23,976
- Create a corresponding Ingest configuration without making any modifications
- In Premiere, configure the ingestion to use my settings
- Import my footage in my project and set the interpretation to 23,976 frames/s (select footage in project --> right click --> modify and set to 23,976 frames/s)
- Cancel the encoding queue in Media Encoder, reset the state, delete the stale proxy and setup the interpretation to 23,976 frames/s (right click and modify to 23,976 frames/s)
- Restart the encoding in Media Encoder

When it finishes my proxies are out of sync (enabling and disabling the proxies in Premiere makes the footage skip to a different frame)

What am I doing wrong? How should I interpret this? Anything in particular I should read?

What's also strange is even the footage I shot in 23,976 is out of sync with its proxies. I am struggling to understand what's going on here... Thanks for any tip or advice.

EDIT: I possibly found the source of the issue. The frame rate set in Media Encoding is not properly set it Premiere. Here are screen shot showing the discrepancy (sorry it's in french but it's easy to relate to the settings concerned).

[image: Settings in Media Encoder showing 23,976 frames/s]

[image: In ingestion settings it's showing 29,95 frames/s]

As we can see from the screenshots, there is a discrepancy between what's set in Media Encoder (23,976 fps) and Premiere's ingestion summary (showing 59,94 fps). What am I missing? I just created this set of presets and I made sure they're the same in ME and Premiere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to delete the presets I was using in both Premiere and Media Encoder and start from scratch. Somehow these 2 had gotten out of sync and the presets in PrPro and Media Encoder we're not using the same frame rate. I didn't understand how this got out of sync unfortunately.